# Make the Div element wrap the lines like the Span do

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a `div` element wrap the lines like the `span` do?

[JSFiddle for testing](https://jsfiddle.net/yn0qoyhr/1/)

Here I used `span` tag to make the output looks like it was highlighed by a [yellow highlighter pen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlighter). All works like it should:

```
<p><span class="highlighter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
id est laborum.</span></p>

<style>
.highlighter { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
```

[image]

Let's see another case. Now, I have multiple paragraphs, and I want to use the above way to style them. I can use this way:

```
<p><span class="highlighter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
<p><span class="highlighter">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></p>
```

[image]

... The output looks fine, but I don't like this kind of markup, because it force me to repeat `class` on every paragraph.

What I want is something like this:

```
<div class="highlighter">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

... But now, the output fails - the large yellow rectange is not what I want.

[image]

Is there way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make `display: inline;` example here
https://jsfiddle.net/serGlazkov/dhftwqt9/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not OK with the trailing highlighted part, add `span`s:

```css
.highlighter span{
  background: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlighter">
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</sapn></p>
  <p><span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></p>
</div>
```